# Wrap groups of elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a list of elements and I want to group them with div starting with the first element and ends with BREAK class then start a new group after the class BREAK.

So the code below,

```
<div class="test">Test 0</div>
<div class="test">Test 1</div>
<div class="break">Break 0</div>
<div class="test">Test 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 3</div>
<div class="break">Break 1</div>
<div class="test">Test 4</div>
<div class="test">Test 5</div>
<div class="test">Test 6</div>
```

Would become,

```
<div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="test">Test 0</div>
        <div class="test">Test 1</div>
        <div class="break">Break 0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="test">Test 2</div>
        <div class="test">Test 3</div>
        <div class="break">Break 1</div>
    </div>
        <div class="group">
        <div class="test">Test 4</div>
        <div class="test">Test 5</div>
        <div class="test">Test 6</div>
        <div class="break">Add last break element</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

And append a div element in the last group.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure what you meant by *"append a div element in the last group"*..? you want to add a `.break` in last group..? Also, do you have a parent element for this divs, or are they just let loose in `<body>`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can also do something like this: first you insert one more `.break` to all `.test` parent container, then using `wrapAll` method wrap groups properly:

```js
$('.test').parent().append('<div class="break">Break 2</div>').
find('.test + .break').each(function() {
    $(this).prevUntil('.break, .group').add(this).wrapAll('<div class="group"></div>');
});
```

```css
.group {
  padding: 3px;
  background: #BFECBE;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="test">Test 0</div>
    <div class="test">Test 1</div>
    <div class="break">Break 0</div>
    <div class="test">Test 2</div>
    <div class="test">Test 3</div>
    <div class="break">Break 1</div>
    <div class="test">Test 4</div>
    <div class="test">Test 5</div>
    <div class="test">Test 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For code simplicity this the best answer. Thanks @dfsq

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably go with simple: Loop through them with a container you add to, add a new container every time you see `break`:

```
var div;
$("selector for the divs").each(function() {
    if (!div) {
        div = $("<div>").insertBefore(this);
    }
    div.append(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass("break")) {
        div = undefined;
    }
});
if (div) {
    $("<div>last break</div>").addClass("break").appendTo(div);
}
```

Example (I added a `wrapper` class so we could see the effect when adding):

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
  var div;
  $("#container > div").each(function() {
    if (!div) {
      div = $("<div>").addClass("wrapper").insertBefore(this);
    }
    div.append(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass("break")) {
      div = undefined;
    }
  });
  if (div) {
    $("<div>last break</div>").addClass("break").appendTo(div);
  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: blue;
}
.break {
  color: red;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="go" value="Go">
<div id="container">
<div class="test">Test 0</div>
<div class="test">Test 1</div>
<div class="break">Break 0</div>
<div class="test">Test 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 3</div>
<div class="break">Break 1</div>
<div class="test">Test 4</div>
<div class="test">Test 5</div>
<div class="test">Test 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this code is working fine,you can  check the fiddle and demo here as well

```js
$("div.test").each(function() {
  if (!$(this).nextAll(".break").length)
    $(".test").last().after('<div class="break">Add last break element</div>');
  if (!$(this).parents(".group").length)
    $(this).add($(this).nextUntil('.break+.test').andSelf()).wrapAll('<div class="group" />');


});
```

```css
.group {
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Test 0</div>
<div class="test">Test 1</div>
<div class="break">Break 0</div>
<div class="test">Test 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 3</div>
<div class="break">Break 1</div>
<div class="test">Test 4</div>
<div class="test">Test 5</div>
<div class="test">Test 6</div>
```

```
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xyzsgzb2/3/)